# Why does pickle not see the class 'painter' when loading?

Tags: python, pickle

I am working with a o.o.p and trying to use pickle to load a list of lines I save in a .txt file. I can save the data with pickle, but I am not sure why it can't see 'painter' after I have initialized it.

```
class LoadButton(MTButton):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoadButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.buttonLoad = kwargs.get('painter')
    def on_release(self, touch):
        if touch.device != 'wm_pen':
            newLoad = self.buttonLoad
            loadFile = open('savefiles/savetest.txt', 'rb')
            newpainter = painter
            scatter.remove_widget(painter) # if removed error: EOF, no data read
            # error: local var 'painter' referenced before assignment
            oldlines = pickle.load(loadFile)
            painter = newpainter
            scatter.add_widget(painter)
            pprint.pprint(oldlines)
            loadFile.close()
            return True
```

Any help would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: It seems that this error has nothing to do with pickle, except that its cause and a use of pickle occur in the same piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `painter = newpainter` creates a local variable `painter`, even if after the part when you call the global `painter`.
Do something like this:

```
painter_ = newpainter
scatter.add_widget(painter_)
```

EDIT: But why don't you use only `painter`?

```
        scatter.remove_widget(painter)
        oldlines = pickle.load(loadFile)
        scatter.add_widget(painter)
```

EDIT 2:
Example:

```
>>> bar = 'Bar'
>>> def foo():
...     bar  # This is the local bar. It has not been assigned a value yet.
...     bar = 'Local Bar'  # Here I assign a value to the bar.
... 
>>> foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in foo
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'bar' referenced before assignment
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks the painter_ = newpainter really helped. It unpickles the lines and prints the lines in the command line, but it doesn't actually display the lines on the screen from original global class 'painter', so you can see your image again. Not sure why.